# Start activity, stop timer, change values from another class

Tags: android

I don't know neither how to write my question so I hope you will understand from my code:
So i have this EXAMPLE code:

MAIN:

```
 public class ListImageButton extends Activity {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.list);
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.list );
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(
                    new OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                android.view.View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

//HERE THIS IS WORKING

                boolean_toast = false;
                timer.cancel();
                zanimivosti.cancel();

                Intent intent = new Intent(ListImageButton.this,
                        ANOTHER_ACTIVITY.class);
                startActivity(intent);


                        }
                });
            ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
            items.add( "item1");
            items.add( "item2");
            ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter( this, items);
            lv.setAdapter( adapter );
        }
    }
```

And the ADAPTER:

```
 public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public ListAdapter(Context context,
                            List<String> items ) { 
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }

        public int getCount() {                        
            return items.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {     
            return items.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {  
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
            String item = items.get(position);
            View v = null;
            if( convertView != null )
                v = convertView;
            else
                v = inflater.inflate( R.layout.item, parent, false);
            TextView itemTV = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.item);
            itemTV.setText( item );
            ImageButton button = 
                (ImageButton)v.findViewById( R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(
                        new OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {

    //HERE THIS IS NOT WORKING

                boolean_toast = false;
                timer.cancel();
                zanimivosti.cancel();

                Intent intent = new Intent(ListImageButton.this,
                        ANOTHER_ACTIVITY.class);
                startActivity(intent);


                            }
                        });
            return v;
        }

        private Context context;
        private List<String> items;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
    }
```

So I would like to stop some timers and cancel some toast that I have in the main activity/class, and also I would like to start a new activity.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I thought about it and the answer was very simple..looks like I was to tired to think about it..
I made this function in the main activity:

```
public static void preklopi() {

    boolean_toast = false;
    cas = 0;
    perioda = 0;
    timer.cancel();
    zanimivosti.cancel();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Context, kasper.api.Najdi_osebo.class);
    Context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

And then I called the function from main activity in the other class..